# SharePoint 2010 production WFE server not responding every 2 months I am doing force restart from physical location.What could be the reason?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, windows-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I am struggling to resolve following issue.

We have 3 tier farm, In that WFE server hosted central admin site but every 2-3 months(its approximately) not responding while accessing through remote desktop keep on loading and applications also not able to access keep on loading only. Then I am doing force restart from physical location.

**I found following event viewer system logs:**

Event ID:55

Description: The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume D

**Event ID: 41**

Description: The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

**Event ID:134**

Description:The transaction resource manager on volume C: encountered an error during recovery.  The resource manager will continue recovery.

Event Viewer Application Logs:

every 2 days i am getting this warning. I believe it might not be a reason to not responding server.

**Warning Event ID: 7362**

Description:

Object Cache: The super user account utilized by the cache is not configured. This can increase the number of cache misses, which causes the page requests to consume unneccesary system resources.
 To configure the account use the following command 'stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname portalsuperuseraccount -propertyvalue account -url webappurl'. The account should be any account that has Full Control access to the SharePoint databases but is not an application pool account.
 Additional Data:
 Current default super user account: SHAREPOINT\system

**Event ID : 2137--> almost every one hour its occuring.**

Desription:

The SharePoint Health Analyzer detected an error.  One or more services have started or stopped unexpectedly.
The following services are managed by SharePoint, but their running state does not match what SharePoint expects: SPAdminV4.  This can happen if a service crashes or if an administrator starts or stops a service using a non-SharePoint interface.  If SharePoint-managed services do not match their expected running state, SharePoint will be unable to correctly distribute work to the service.
SharePoint was unable to automatically repair this error.

To stop or start a service managed by SharePoint, use the SharePoint service management interface in the SharePoint Central Administration Site.  If a service has crashed, restart the service manually on the affected servers by running "net start [service name]" from a command prompt. For more information about this rule, see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142683".
Trying to chk dsk for any filysystem errors

I am afraid to do Chk Dsk D: \F or \R because its asking to dismount

C:\Users\farmadminaccount>chkdsk D: /f
The type of the file system is NTFS.

Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first.
ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID.
Would you like to force a dismount on this volume? (Y/N)
Please help me on this issue.